# Does CPU waits for DEVICE to let it finish its kernel execution....?

Tags: cuda

Does host wait for device to finish its execution compeletely?
e.g. the program has the structure as follows

```
// cpu code segment

// data transfer from host to device

QUESTION - WILL CPU WAIT FOR DEVICE TO FINISH TRANSFER? IF NO, IS IT POSSIBLE? IF YES, HOW?

// kernel launch

QUESTION - WILL CPU WAIT FOR DEVICE TO LET IT FINISH KERNEL EXECUTION (CONSIDERING KERNEL EXECUTION WILL TAKE NOTABLE TIME say-5 sec)? IF NO, IS IT POSSIBLE? IF YES, HOW?

// data transfer from device to host

// program terminates after printing some information
```

Comment: @Spontifixus, isn't it clear? I am wondering the same as OP did.

Comment: @Primož'c0dehunter'Kralj You're right. The question is just badly formatted.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The synchronization functions of the CUDA run-time can let you achieve what you want.

`cudaDeviceSynchronize()`:

When you call this function, the CPU will wait until the device has completed ALL its work, whether it is memory copy or kernel execution.

`cudaStreamSynchronize(cudaStream)`:

This function will block the CPU until the specified CUDA stream has finished its execution. Other CUDA streams will continue their execution asynchronously.

Comment: To expand on this, there are two questions: 1) for the data transfer the CPU will block and wait for the transfer to complete if you use `cudaMemcpy()` - if you use the asynchronous versions (`cudaMemcpyAsync()`) then it is asynchronous and the CPU will not block (obviously); 2) kernel launches are always asynchronous as described in the programming guide - synchronising after kernel call (using `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` (or stream equivalent) or calling a synchronous memcpy will cause the CPU to block.

Comment: Also remember that if you're using the GPU then ideally you would copy data and execute kernels asynchronously - may as well make good use of all the engines at your disposal!